# Force XDocument to not use namespace prefix if namespace is also defined as default

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file with default namespace specified with and without namespace prefix. When I generate xml output I'm getting all xml elements prefixed. Is there way to get rid of the prefixes since I'm using the default namespace?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml =
            "<root xmlns='default-namespace' xmlns:key='default-namespace'>" +
            "  <node1></node1>" +
            "  <node2></node2>" +
            "</root>";
        var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var output = document.ToString();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
<key:root xmlns="default-namespace" xmlns:key="default-namespace">
  <key:node1></key:node1>
  <key:node2></key:node2>
</key:root>
```

What I'd expect:

```
<root xmlns="default-namespace" xmlns:key="default-namespace">
  <node1></node1>
  <node2></node2>
</root>
```

Unfortunately I can't remove the duplicated namespace declaration. The actual xml file I'm using is provided by another party and I need to do as less modifications as possible.

Comment: In my view it is a shortcoming of the LINQ to XML object models that prefixes of node names are not stored and that way the serializer has to choose a prefix based on namespace declaration attributes when serializing a tree to a string of XML. It seems that the current implementation of ToString() or Save uses the last found namespace declaration of  a namespace as changing the order to `<root  xmlns:key='default-namespace' xmlns='default-namespace'>` gives a different result but that is not something to rely on obviously. If prefixes matter, choose a different tree model like XmlDocument.

Answer (score -2):

You Can Use String.Replace Method to Get The Required XML Format ...

```
var xml ="<root xmlns='default-namespace' xmlns:key='default-namespace'>" +
         "  <node1></node1>" +
         "  <node2></node2>" +
         "</root>";
        var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var output = document.ToString().Replace("key:", string.Empty);
```

Comment: This is considered a hack. What if node 1 contains the value <node1>key:something</node1>